# How do I look up exit codes for applications?

Tags: documentation, exit, exit-status

I'm having difficulty locating a comprehensive up-to-date list of error codes from Bash.  e.g.:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sdx; echo Exit code $?
Unknown device, --name=, --path=, or absolute path in /dev/ or /sys expected.
Exit code 4
```

How is one supposed to look up such exit codes?

Comment: It should be noted that your example, `udevadm`, is *not* a bash script...

Comment: If one of these answers solves your issue, please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: See also [What return/exit values can I use in bash functions/scripts?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168153/what-return-exit-values-can-i-use-in-bash-functions-scripts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tl;dr **Exit codes are application specific.**

There are some loose conventions. `false` and anything successful prefixed with `!` (like `! true`) in POSIX shells return exit code 1, but a developer can use any exit code between 0 and 255 for whatever they want. Ultimately you have to look at its documentation (in the best case) or the code (in the worst case) to know what it means. For programs with `man` pages exit codes will often be listed in a section named `EXIT STATUS` (GNU tools like `find`).

Some popular meanings are listed in `/usr/include/sysexits.h` - I try to use them whenever possible. As [@AnsgarEsztermann points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162677/how-do-i-look-up-exit-codes-for-applications/162680#comment266527_162680), these are not a Bash reference, or even an application reference except for those who choose to use it (C/C++ developers primarily [according to the ABS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)).

Comment: I see. Thanks l0b0 and jasonwryan. So I conclude that particular command is improperly documented.

Comment: In case this has not become clear from l0b0's answer: these exit codes are not "bash exit codes". They belong entirely to the exiting commands, and they will not change if these commands are called in a different way that does not involve bash.

Comment: The values in `sysexits.h` are pretty much unused except by `procmail` and company. Only sendmail (and some other MTAs) care about them.

Answer (score 13):

There are a handful of exit codes with [reserved special meanings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html):

```
Exit Code Number   Meaning
1      Catchall for general errors
2      Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)
126    Command invoked cannot execute
127    "command not found"
128+n  Fatal error signal "n"
130    Script terminated by Ctrl-C
255*   Exit status out of range
```

Everything below 125 is fair game for developers, and can really only be divined, as [l0b0 notes in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162680/6761), by reading the `man` page for the application, or the source code, to determine what the code signifies (if, indeed, it is documented at all).

Comment: It should also be noted that these are "reserved" only by *convention* - there is no enforcement (other than good sense) actually preventing, for example, an application using `1` or `2` to mean `success`. Everything is actually fair game for developers.

Comment: To expand, they "should [...] be avoided for user-specified exit parameters."

Comment: @AndrewMedico This isn't quite true: 0 for success isn't just a matter of convention, it's built into a lot of tools including shells (`&&`, `||`, `!`, `set -e`, …).

Comment: The entries for 1 and 2 don't make much sense. 1 and 2 are not reserved. Bash builtins don't even always use 2 — in fact they seem to use 1 for errors; other shells use different error codes (usually 1 or 2). “Missing keyword” and `diff` aren't about shell builtins. 1 and 2 are both common catchalls.