# What return/exit values can I use in bash functions/scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, function, exit, exit-status

I want to know what return values we can use that will not be mistaken by for ex. SIGINT?

ex.:

```
$sleep 10
$#hit ctrl+c
$echo $?
130
```

so I know I must not use anything like `return 130` or `exit 130`

so this would be misleading:

```
$function FUNC(){ return 130; };FUNC;echo $?
130
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162677/how-do-i-look-up-exit-codes-for-applications

Comment: @jasonwryan you mean this one right? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162682/30352 thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any number between 0 to 255 except for **reserved exit codes** ([click here to know more](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF))

Comment: despite it speaks against `exit 1`, I think it is ok for general non specific errors, but if we want to identify a certain exit value, it just must not be 1 or the others on the list you provided

Comment: here are that values copied to stackexchange sites http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162682/30352

Answer (score 10):

The exit status of a process is encoded as a value **between 0 and 255**, so that's all you can use as an exit code. If you pass a value outside that range, most shells use the remainder modulo 256. Some shells allow a wider range of integer values for functions.

The only rule for exit codes is that **0 means success and any other value means failure**. This rule goes beyond unix: it's also a common convention on other operating systems (including DOS, Windows, and many embedded systems that have a notion of exit code, but VMS does things differently). In unix systems, it's baked into the shell's boolean constructs (`if`, `while`, `&&`, `||`, `!`, `set -e`, …), into `make`, and followed by all the standard utilities. In POSIX C programs,[`EXIT_SUCCESS`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdlib.h.html) is 0 and `EXIT_FAILURE` is some non-zero value (usually 1).

There is no rule (de facto or de jure) regarding the choice of exit codes for failure. Only a few POSIX utilities mandate specific failure status codes:

- The `!` shell operator returns 1 if its operand returns 0. The `&&` and `||` operator pass the status from the last command.
- [`cmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cmp.html) and [`diff`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/diff.html) return 1 for different files and ≥2 for error conditions.
- [`expr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html) returns 1 
  if the expression evaluates to zero or null, 2 for an invalid expression, and ≥3 for other errors.
- [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) returns 1 for “not found” and ≥2 for error conditions. Many search commands follow this (but not `find`, which returns 0 if no file matches).
- [`mesg`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mesg.html) returns 0 for yes, 1 for no, and ≥2 for error.
- [`patch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/patch.html) returns 1 if a hunk was rejected and ≥2 for other errors.
- [`sort -c`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sort.html) returns 1 if the file data isn't sorted and ≥2 for errors.
- [`compress`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/compress.html) and [`localedef`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/localedef.html) define some small values for specific errors.

There is a common, but not universal idea that larger values mean worse failures. For commands that test a boolean condition such as `grep` (is this pattern present?) and `diff` (are these files identical?), 1 means “no” and higher values indicate an error. In addition, **values from 126 up are rarely used**, as they are baked into the shell (and POSIX commands `command`, `env`, `nice`, `nohup` and `time`):

- 126 and 127 indicate a failure to invoke an external command;
- values above 128 in `$?` indicate a command that was terminated by a signal.

[`/usr/include/sysexits.h`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE) lists some values with their meanings, but it's from sendmail and I've never seen it outside programs that are unrelated to email delivery.

In summary, return 0 for success, and either 1 or 2 for failure. If you need to distinguish between failure cases, start at 1 and increase the value for worse failures.

Comment: cool, so "2 Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)" can basically be ignored, as it seems to only happen as an exit value of bash builtins right? in other words, if I always set the return/exit value properly, it will not be the value of the last executed command even if such is a bash builtin that could return 2. So I can safely go from 0 to 125 (as I will ever use that much hehe)! thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower What do you mean by “misuse of shell builtins”?

Comment: @Gilles see the link from the accepted answer (the ABS guide). It says code 2 is for misuse of shell builtins, such as a missing keyword.

Comment: @muru [That table](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF)? The entries for 1 and 2 don't make much sense. 1 and 2 are not reserved. Bash builtins don't even always use 2 — in fact they seem to use 1 for errors; other shells use different error codes (usually 1 or 2). “Missing keyword” and `diff` aren't about shell builtins. 1 and 2 are both common catchalls.

Answer (score 5):

### Exit Status Conventions

Technically, you can use any value between 0 and 255. However, there are a number of existing conventions you can use:

- Exit code 1 as a [catch-all for general errors](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).
- Exit codes 64-78 from [sysexits.h](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%204.3-RELEASE&format=html) to indicate the class of error. You can generally look these up in */usr/include/sysexits.h*, which is installed by the Debian/Ubuntu libc6-dev package.
- Exit codes from [errno.h](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno). You can also look these up with the *errno* command from the moreutils package. On my system, running `errno --list` currently displays 134 defined errors.

### Document and Display

In general, it's a good idea to document the exit codes used within your script, or at least which convention you're following. It may also be useful to display a distinctive message before exiting, such as:

```
# using sysexits.h
echo "EX_USAGE: invalid argument: $1" > /dev/stderr
exit 64

# using errno.h
echo "ENOENT: File not found: $file" > /dev/stderr
exit 2
```

Comment: `errno.h` lists return codes for C functions. It is not used by external commands. The values depend on the flavor of unix and they aren't in the right range (0–125). As for `sysexits.h`, it's only used in a few email-related programs, it isn't a de facto standard for return codes.