# Check if there is a certain file in a directory

Tags: files, directory, test

Hi I'm trying to do an if which gets a path to a directory as an argument and checks if file.txt is in the directory.And returns 1 if it is , 0 otherwise.

```
     if [ -e $1/file.txt ]; then
         exit 1
     else exit 0
     fi
```

Also i've tried ls method

```
     ls $1/file.txt && exit 1 || exit 0
```

Is there any other method? Or i am missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-to-check-if-a-regular-file-exists-or-not-using-bash correct switch is -f, not -e...

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou No, `-e` is the correct switch. `-f` tests whether `file.txt` exists and is a regular file. `-e` just tests if the file exists.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a file `file.txt` is present in the directory passed as the first argument to the script or function, use

```
[ -e "$1/file.txt" ]
```

[Don't forget to double-quote variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

This succeeds if the file exists, and fails if the file doesn't exist. Failure includes the case where the file exists but can't be reached, e.g. because you don't have the permission to traverse the directory.

Note that in shell scripts, and when it comes to process exit statuses, 0 means success and 1 (or more, up to 125) means failure. See [What return/exit values can I use in bash functions/scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168153/what-return-exit-values-can-i-use-in-bash-functions-scripts/168182#168182) and [Default exit code when process is terminated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99112/default-exit-code-when-process-is-terminated/99134#99134) for more details. So if you want to check whether a file exists, your script or function must return 0 if the file exists and 1 otherwise. Your snippet does the opposite: it checks if the file doesn't exist.

```
 if [ -e "$1/file.txt" ]; then
    exit 0
 else
    exit 1
 fi
```

is just a more complicated way of writing

```
[ -e "$1/file.txt" ]
exit
```

(`exit` with no status argument uses the status of the previously executed command). And if this is at the end of the script then `exit` is redundant.

If you did want to check that the file doesn't exist then you would invert the command with the `!` shell operator:

```
! [ -e "$1/file.txt" ]
```

or the `!` `test`/`[` operator:

```
[ ! -e "$1/file.txt" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ -e "$1/file.txt" ]
```

In shells/`[` implementations where it is supported¹ will return true if one can do a `stat()` system call on the file whose path is the expansion of `$1/file.txt`.

It's equivalent to:

```
if ls -Ld -- "$1/file.txt" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

For the equivalent of:

```
if ls -d -- "$1/file.txt" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

that is whether a `lstat()` can be done on the file, it would be:

```
if [ -e "$1/file.txt" ] || [ -L "$1/file.txt" ]
```

to cover the "broken" symlink case (for which `-e` would return false as it tests for existence after symlink resolution).

Now, `stat()`, `lstat()` failing doesn't necessarily mean that the file doesn't exist, `stat()`/`lstat()` could fail with other error conditions than ENOENT (no entry) ENOTDIR (a path component is not a directory). It could be that you don't have search access to any of the directory component for instance.

With the `ls` approach, you can remove the `2>&1` for `ls` to tell you the error. [With `[`, you won't know unless you use `zsh` where you can use `$ERRNO`](//stackoverflow.com/a/40046642).

If you don't  have *search* access to the directory, you may still have *read* access, so you could still read the directories content to see if there's a file by that name.

With `zsh`, that can be done with `()(($#)) $1/file.txt(N)`, an anonymous function that returns true if it receives at least one argument (`()(($#))`) to which we pass the list of files matching the `$1/file.txt(N)` glob, `(N)` being to turn on `NULLGLOB` for that one glob.

A separate problem with `$1/file.txt` is the case where `$1` is `/`, in which case that becomes `//file.txt` which on some systems is not the same as `/file.txt`.

So with `zsh`, to check whether `file.txt` exists as an entry in the `$1` directory:

```
exists() {
  local file="${1%/}/file.txt"

  zmodload zsh/system
  local ERRNO=0
  [ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ] && return 0
  case $errnos[ERRNO] in
    (ENOENT|ENOTDIR) return 1;; # does not exist for sure
    (*) ()(($#)) $file && return 0;;
  esac
  return 2 # meaning: don't know
}
```

With other shells, you could try:

```
enoent_error=$(
  LC_ALL=C ls -d /surely-does-not-exist 2>&1)
)
enoent_error=${enoent_error##*:}

enotdir_error=$(
  LC_ALL=C ls -d /bin/sh/foo)
)
enotdir_error=${enotdir_error##*:}

exists() (
  file=${1%/}/file.txt
  if error=$(LC_ALL=C ls -d -- "$file" 2>&1 > /dev/null); then
    return 0 # exists for sure
  else
    case $error in
      (*:"$enoent_error"|*:"$enotdir_error")
        return 1;; # does not exist for sure
    esac
  fi
  return 2 # don't know
}
```

That assumes `ls` error messages in the C locale follow the `*: fixed error message` pattern where the `fixed error message` is different for each error condition but always the same for a given error and does not contain `:` (on my system only `ETOOMANYREFS` (*Too many references: cannot splice*) has a `:` in the corresponding standard libc error message, but that's not an errno returned by `lstat()`, and anyway *cannot splice* is not found in other error messages).

---

<sup>¹ `[` aka `test` didn't support `-e` initially. `ksh` introduced `-a` first (which then doubled as both a unary and binary operator), for *accessible* I believe (which in a way is more correct), which was later renamed to `-e` (though most implementations still support `-a` as well) and that's `-e` that POSIX specifies for the standard `test`/`[` utility. `/bin/sh` on Solaris 10 and older is still a non-POSIX Bourne shell and its `[` builtin still doesn't support `[ -e` nor `[ -a`, so you'd need to resort to `ls` or call `/bin/test` if you were to use that shell (though you'd rather use a POSIX shell like `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` there).</sup>