# How do I exit with a failure code if the wrong number of args are passed to my script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit-status

I'm using bash.  How can I exit with a non-success code if my script has the wrong number of arguments?

I have this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Should be three parameters to this script -- [CWD driver-directory side-file]"
fi
```

but then the script continues.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168153/117549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to call `exit`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Should be three parameters to this script -- [CWD driver-directory side-file]"
    exit 9
fi
```

Using any non-negative integer between 1 and 255 that you like or want.